# Group cohomology of the product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Let $m \geq 2$ be a positive integer and $C_m$ be a finite cyclic group of order $m$.

**My question**: How to compute the cohomology groups $H^i(C_m \times C_n, A)$ for $i > 0$ in the following two cases:

1. $A = \mathbb{Z}$ is a trivial $C_m \times C_n$-module,
2. $m=n$ is even and $A = \mathbb{Z}$ with an action of $C_m$ given by $k \cdot z = (-1)^k z$.

**EDIT Sept. 14**: I have almost figure out the result via **Approach 4** , after having been collaborating with my roommate, by taking a particular resolution. I shall sort them out in a few weeks and post it as an answer. Thank you all for your attention!

---

**My attempts**: I have obtained a bunch of partial results, but failed to the general result.

**Attempt 1**: (Kunneth formula) In the first case when $A=\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, one may apply the Kunneth formula to get the cohomology group, but the discussion is too tedious, full of mess with parity on $m$ and $n$. More unsatisfactory to me is that the Kunneth's formula in my mind is the Exercise 6.1.8 in Weibel's book:

> **Kunneth's formula**: There is a split short exact sequence
> $$
> 0 \rightarrow \bigoplus_{p+q=n} H^p(G,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^q(H,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^n(G \times H, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{p+q=n+1} \mathrm{Tor}_{1}^{\mathbb{Z}}(H^p(G,\mathbb{Z}),H^q(H,\mathbb{Z})).
> $$
> where $\mathbb{Z}$ above are trivial modules.

, which only treats the trivial coefficient case.

**Attempt 2**: (Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence) Taking $G=C_m \times C_n$ and $H=C_n$, we have the convergent spectral sequence
$$
\mathcal{E}: E_2^{p,q} = H^p(C_m, H^q(C_n, \mathbb{Z})) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(C_m \times C_m, \mathbb{Z}).
$$
Since $G$ is an abelian group and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a trivial module, the conjugation actions of $G/H \cong C_m$ on the cohomology groups $H^q(C_n, \mathbb{Z})$ are trivial. So we explicitly compute the $E_2$-page as
$$
\begin{matrix}
 \mathbb{Z}/n & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/d & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/d & \cdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
 \mathbb{Z}/n & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/d & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/d & \cdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
E_2^{0,0}=\mathbb{Z} & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/m & 0 & \mathbb{Z}/m & \cdots \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Then $E_{\infty}^{p,q} = E_{2}^{p,q}$ by carefully checking the direction of arrows. Then we know directly:

- $H^0(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$,
- $H^{\text{odd}}(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

But for cohomology group of even degree, I can only obtain a filtration of the cohomology:
$$
H^{2i}(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \supseteq \ast \supseteq \ast \cdots \supseteq \ast = 0
$$
where the subquotients are $\mathbb{Z}/m$, $\mathbb{Z}/d$ for $(i-1)$ times and one $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Then **if everything splits**, then
$$
H^{2i}(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/m \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/d)^{i-1} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n.
$$
But **how can I see the splitting of this filtration**?

**Attempt 3**: (Inflation-restriction exact sequence) Actually the inf-res sequence is derived from the above spectral sequence, yet I still tried to gain something from it. We can only use the $n=1$ version of the inf-res sequence, which gives
$$
0 \rightarrow H^1(C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{inf}} H^1(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{res}} H^1(C_m, \mathbb{Z})^{C_n} \xrightarrow{\mathrm{transgression}} H^2(C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \cdots.
$$
This turns into
$$
0 \rightarrow 0 \xrightarrow{\mathrm{inf}} H^1(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{res}} 0 \xrightarrow{\mathrm{transgression}} 0.
$$
hence
$$
H^1(C_m \times C_n, \mathbb{Z}) \cong 0.
$$
This can be seen from the spectral sequence above. So unfortunately, I got nothing new.

(*EDIT*: I have corrected the calculation here, as I mixed up the homology and cohomology of cyclic groups)

---

These are all my attempts by now, yet unfortunately they all fail to give a complete result, or even a promising method to treat the second case where $\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* a trivial module.

So is there any way to settle down these cohomology groups? Or could someone provide some reference on the *result* of the cohomology group?

Thank you so much for answering and commenting! :)

---

**EDIT**: The comment by Dietrich Burde is quite useful, but I would like to see a more direct approach since this question only appears in a final exam of an elementary course on homological algebra, so it wouldn't require so much machinery that hard to establish during a two-hour exam.

---

So **Approach 4**: can we create an explicit resolution to do the job? Yet the standard resolution is quite complicated. :(

Here I found a resolution provided by Sasha: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36730/describe-the-second-cohomology-group-h2z-n-times-z-n-k . But I cannot found the pattern for the general term of the resolution.

Comment: For $H^2(G_1\times G_2,\Bbb Z)$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363395/on-2-cocycles-defined-on-direct-product)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! Now we have **Attempt 4** via the "standard" resolution. :)

Comment: But the Künneth formula works quite well there, because we know already $H^0$ and $H^1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry to be silly, but do you mean that once we know $H^0$ and $H^1$, we can inductively work out all $H^n$ with Kunneth formula? I have added the Kunneth formula (in my mind) to the post. Moreover, is there a Kunneth formula for general coefficient? (In order to treat the second case where $A$ is no longer a trivial module.)

Comment: I have found a reference [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj24e6f8Nz5AhVBNewKHXcJAoQ4ChAWegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcentral.bac-lac.gc.ca%2F.item%3Fid%3DTC-OWTU-7276%26op%3Dpdf%26app%3DLibrary%26oclc_number%3D835911846&usg=AOvVaw3Q612Z-glXz5KULBEdmjZe) for the cohomology of a product $C_n\times C_m$, section $6.3.1$, and other sections.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! It seems that it is a quite systematic approach, especially on the entire information on the cohomology ring! I shall read that. :)   (Though as a problem in qualify exam, the cohomology group above may be easier to be calculated by hand than the huge amount of work.)

Comment: It is also possible that the general result from the literature is easy to simplify, when you apply your very special assumptions. Here I would start with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $A=\Bbb Z$, or even $m$ and $n$ different prime powers. You need to check what exactly you are allowed to use. I think, one should use all what is published.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I totally agree with you. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm quite confused at the downvote. Could the downvoter explain the reason so that I can improve the post? Thank you!

Comment: The Künneth formula does hold with non-trivial coefficients (with some hypothesis that hold in your case) See Ken Brown's textbook "Cohomology of Groups". The simplest way to do what you want is to use the Kunneth formula, and what you call a mess of parities is just what they are. You learn to deal with it and move on.

Comment: There you will also find  a way to construct a resolution of a direct product by tensoring resolutions of the factors. If you do that with the periodic resolutions of cyclic groups you get a minimal resolution for you group. It is not difficult to compute what you want using that resolution and the direct definition of cohomology.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ahha, thank you for your hint! So it seems that essentially what I have been doing via **Approach 4** (by construct resolution via tensoring resolutions) is exactly reproving the Kunneth formula in this case.  Thank you for remind me of that and providing the reference! I will look into that! :)